# React Native: What file is responsible for the build of an app?

Tags: react-native, build, compilation

I'm currently working on a project for work that will require me to play around with the way in which react-naive apps build and I'm wondering what file/files are actually responsible for the building of an app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, React Native using [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) build tool for building android apps. You can find an executable file named `gradlew` inside of `android` directory. For iOS, I'm not so sure, but I think RN use `xcodebuild` command line tool.